# Проектирование БД с месяцами и числами

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Кто может подсказать, как правильно спроектировать БД, где таблицы будут содержать месяц и каждый день месяца. Например:
сводная таблица:
поле: организация,значение,итого
и нужно чтобы в каждой таблице был месяц и все дни месяца, не совсем понимаю, как правильно это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь ты тоже любишь издеваться над SQL

```
SELECT days_with_seq.SeqValue, days_with_seq.`Day`, DAYOFWEEK(days_with_seq.`Day`) as DOW_NUM,
    CASE DAYOFWEEK(days_with_seq.`Day`)
    WHEN 1 THEN "Завтра на работу"
    WHEN 2 THEN "Понедельник день тяжолый"
    WHEN 3 THEN "Вторник"
    WHEN 4 THEN "Середина недели"
    WHEN 5 THEN "Маленькая пятница"
    WHEN 6 THEN "Тяпница"
    WHEN 7 THEN "Выходной"
        ELSE "Ошибка?"
    END AS DOW
FROM (
    SELECT SeqValue, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL sequence.SeqValue DAY) AS "Day"
    FROM (SELECT
        (TWO_1.SeqValue + TWO_2.SeqValue + TWO_4.SeqValue + TWO_8.SeqValue + TWO_16.SeqValue) SeqValue
        FROM
        (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 1 SeqValue) TWO_1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 2 SeqValue) TWO_2
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 4 SeqValue) TWO_4
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 8 SeqValue) TWO_8
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 16 SeqValue) TWO_16
    ) as sequence
) days_with_seq;
```

Comment: А можно пожалуйста пример самих таблиц, как они будут выглядеть? И нужны не наименования дней недели, а числа(1-31).<img src="https://radikal.ru/big/4cdmvwz75obnf" width="100" height="100">  - пример одной из таблиц в excel. Вопрос как реализовать в БД все месяцы и в каждом все дни правильно.

Comment: Михаил мне за вас всю таблицу написать? Первый и последний день месяца `SELECT date_add(NOW(),interval -DAY(NOW())+1 DAY) AS first_day, LAST_DAY(NOW()) AS "last_day";` Я не пойму почему просто взять и не подумать.. Берёшь первый/последний день месяца накладываешь на них диапазон, получаешь все дни.... Записываешь в поля базы... Через INSERT INTO X (y,z) SELECT... и получаешь то что тебе надо... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Можно сделать диапазон по 9му биту, туда целый год поместится...  Заносишь в базу, там будут расписаны все дни. года... Через год запустишь код ещё год будет.